# Why does my google cloud funciton take more than 9 minutes for execution while the same funciton on my local machine takes < 2 mins

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Why does my google cloud funciton take more than 9 minutes for execution while the same funciton on my local machine takes < 2 mins. I am using a python cloud function to extract data from a bigquery table using google bigquery api to a dataframe and then convert the dataframe to a zip file inorder to upload it to google cloud storage.

Comment: Without code/environment information there's no way to answer this question. My gut check is that you're actually suffering from cold start costs. I highly recommend you watch this video for good information about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY

Comment: If you immediately run the same function a 2nd time after you run it the first time, is it still 9 minutes, or does it execute faster?

Comment: Which function type are you using? For all function types, if you return a result before the body of work to be done has completed you will find that your function will get severely throttled and may not even complete.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the [Compute Time in the pricing section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing). By default, the Cloud Functions has 256Mb of memory, and therefore only 400Mhz of compute power. To leverage a full CPU, (2.4Ghz), deploy your function with 2Gb of memory.

Be careful, it's 'only' 2.4Ghz over 1 core. There are a lot of chance that your workstation has 4, 8 or more cores with 3 or 3.5Ghz of speed. Comparison is hard!!

Comment: thanks for your response, I am using a quad core processor locally. However what puzzles me is the execution of a query in the cloud functions using client.query(query).result().to_dataframe() takes around 8 mins in cloud functions however it takes just <2 mins in my local machine.

Comment: Yes, it's python library (not very efficient in term of computing) and you have to load the query result in a dataframe. It's pure computation and data transformation. Sounds logical. Use a 2Gb function and try again.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt responce, I am using a 4 Gb function now and seems to have to same result. if it is an inherent quality then its ok, I concerned if my approach is inefficient

Comment: You have the same 9 minutes+ with function of 4Gb ? Strange...

Comment: its just below 9 minutes with 4 Gb function

Comment: Can you try to create a VM with 1 CPU and to run your script on it? Just to be sure to compare a cloud environment with another cloud environment? There is maybe some accelerator in your CPU that aren't supported/available in the cloud.